# How to add an action opening a dropdown menu in Monaco Editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I know how to add an entry in the context menu of the Monaco editor, with `editor.addAction`. How to add an action which opens a dropdown list, as the "Command Palette" action?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/683), the quick-open api is not yet implemented in monaco-editor. But after a series of in-depth research, I found a somewhat hacker solution.

First, you need to import `IQuickInputService` like below.

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.main.js';
import { IQuickInputService } from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/quickinput/common/quickInput';
```

Then, create our editor.

```js
// Create your editor instance...
let editor = monaco.editor.create(
  // ...
);

// Add a new command, for getting an accessor.
let quickInputCommand = editor.addCommand(0, (accessor, func) => {
  // a hacker way to get the input service
  let quickInputService = accessor.get(IQuickInputService)
  func(quickInputService)
});
```

Finally, as an example, we can add an action.

```js
editor.addAction({
    id: "myQuickInput",
    label: "Test Quick Input",
    run: (editor) => {
         // create quick input
         editor.trigger("", quickInputCommand, (quickInput) => {
             quickInput.pick([
                {
                    type: 'item',
                    id: "my_quick_item",
                    label: "MyQuickItem",
                },
                {
                    type: 'item',
                    id: "my_quick_item2",
                    label: "MyQuickItem2",
                },
                {
                    type: 'item',
                    id: "my_quick_item3",
                    label: "MyQuickItem3",
                },
             ]).then((selected) => {
                console.log(selected)
             })
         })
    }
})
```

For the interface of IQuickInputService, please refer to here [here](https://github.com/opensumi/monaco-editor-core/blob/81b6e48d521218b421b8e28626da4931d38f84bc/src/vs/platform/quickinput/common/quickInput.ts)

If you do it right, when you run the action, you should get the same result as I did.

[image]